# Azure Static Web App - Copying staticwebapp.config.json to output directory

Tags: azure, github, github-actions, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-website-hosting

I'm using a GitHub Action to build and deploy a Vue Azure Static Web App. When using the default template, my `staticwebapp.config.json` file which is at the root of the Vue app gets applied correctly and I see `Copying 'staticwebapp.config.json' to build output` logged.

When using a customized GitHub workflow (shown below) to separate the build and deploy steps which has `skip_app_build` set to `true`, the artifact that gets uploaded/downloaded does not contain the `staticwebapp.config.json` file.

How can I modify the GitHub action to make sure the `staticwebapp.config.json` file [gets copied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration?tabs=github-actions#skip-building-front-end-app) to the *output* directory so that it gets deployed?

```
jobs:
  build:
    if: github.event_name == 'push'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      - name: npm install and run build
        run: npm install && npm run build
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3.1.0
        with:
          name: app
          path: dist/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3.0.0
        with:
          name: app

      - name: Deploy to Azure
        id: deploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_BLUE_STONE_0BAB0F910 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for GitHub integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations ######
          app_location: "" # App source code path relative to repository root
          api_location: "" # Api source code path relative to repository root - optional
          skip_app_build: true
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######
```

Comment: If you locally delete your dist folder and then again locally build do you actually see the staticwebapp.config.json? Maybe it just needs a manual copy to the dist folder after build

Comment: @misha130 - I was able to put the `staticwebapp.config.json` file in the `public` directory, and then it was able to be picked up by the deploy step. Thanks!

Comment: Might as well add an answer to your question to help others that are looking for a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by moving the `staticwebapp.config.json` file to the `public` directory of the Vue app. This made it so that file was in the published artifact.

After doing that, I was able to see `Using staticwebapp.config.json file for configuration information` in the logs during the `static-web-apps-deploy` step.